# Date mismatch in form selection and table in App Maker

Tags: java, mysql, google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am seeing a difference of date selected in form and table widget(where it is displayed.)
What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Use sample app - Project Tracker
2. Create a Project and fill Due Date as Apr, 1 2018
3. Save the data
4. Go to the dashboard and see the difference.

> Due date is selected as Apr, 1 2018 but It's showing as 2018-03-31.

Please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Due date is selected as Apr, 1 2018]
[image: It's showing as 2018-03-31]

Comment: Time zones exist.

Comment: @tehhowch Hi Can you please tell, how to solve this difference issue.

Comment: You need to use timezones. You don't show the relevant code snippets here, so that's all anyone can say. Share the code that accepts, stores, gets, and displays that date. (Edit it into your question)

Answer (score 0):

App Maker stores date values according to the time zone setting in 'App Settings'. So if you enter a date of 4/1/2018 and your client time zone is (GMT-07:00) Denver for example but your App Setting time zone is (GMT-08:00) Los Angeles (which is the default time zone for App Maker), then you would see the "error?" you are describing. To correct this you would want to set the time zone you prefer for your application. See the attached screen shot where to find this setting:

[image: Time Zone Settings]